# how to load unique script in wordpress custome plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i want to add `unique script` if `script file` already there its not been added

i have used following `js` file

1. jquery.min.js
2. slick.min.js
3. custome.js

but `jquery.min.js` have conflict with already added by wordpress and when i remove this `js` file than`$not define` error come so can i resolve this

My code is here

```
wp_register_script('jquery_js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js');
// wp_register_script('jquery', plugins_url('js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__),array(),null,true );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_js');
wp_register_script('slick',  plugins_url('js/slick.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery_js'));
wp_enqueue_script('slick');
wp_register_script('custome', plugins_url('js/custome.js', __FILE__), array('jquery_js'),null,true);
wp_localize_script('custome','ajax_object',array(
    "ajax_url" => admin_url("admin-ajax.php"),
    "base_url" => esc_url( plugins_url( 'img', __FILE__ ) )
));
wp_enqueue_script('custome');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is first to deregister the jquery that comes with WP and then register the new one. I would also recommend you to actually download your jquery.js, instead of trying to load it through CDN. So your function would look something like:

```
wp_register_script(
                wp_deregister_script('jquery');
                wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-3.2.1.min', get_theme_root_uri() . '/my_theme_folder/path_to_jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', true);
                //and so on
                //and so on
               );

wp_enqueue_script('custome');
```

Comment: new error after this `jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.8:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at w.fn.init.w.fn.load`

Comment: check in your source the order of the js scripts that being loaded and if there is a duplicate of the jquery. It sounds like the jquery is still loaded twice

Comment: did you check the source of the page ? Check it and see how the js scripts are loaded, if jqury is loaded more than once